# SQL server - Masking / changing value uniqueidentifier before inserting

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, random, mask

So the main goal is to mask or randomly change value of uniqueidentifier before inserting.

For example:
I have a table

```
Create table Student
(
Student_ID masked WITH (FUNCTION='default()') DEFAULT NEWID()
Student_Name varchar(100),
)
```

Im inserting new data:

```
insert into DDM_Student_Sample values ('B9BC5E61-0F3C-498F-AF2C-1AC16446A846','Stuart Little Joe')
```

The result is the same output as it was inserted, i.e. **uniqueidentifier = 'B9BC5E61-0F3C-498F-AF2C-1AC16446A846'**

I have created a user with login:

```
CREATE USER MAIN_USER FOR LOGIN MAIN_USER; 
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'MAIN_USER';
```

By toturial (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Security/149689/) it says you must create user **without login**. Maybe thats the problem why Student_ID does not change randomly.

In the end, maybe there is another way before inserting data to table change it value randomly. Or I should just change value from front-end? And write something like :

```
model.StudentId = Guid.NewGuid();
model.SaveToDatabase();
```

Comment: you know a GUID is not guaranteed to be unique right?

Comment: The title says SQL Server, but then the <mysql> tag is used. Which product are you actually using?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it is sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic Sql Server Data Masking is designed to prevent accidental exposure of sensitive data. **It doesn't change the actual stored value.** It just applies the mask to values before showing the data. I think that's why it is called *dynamic*

> The result is the same output as it was inserted

I guess, you see the actual value because you have `UNMASK` permission or `CONTROL` permission (which includes `UNMASK`).
Moreover user without `UNMASK` permission can "guess" the actual value with simple select

```
select from Student where Student_ID = 'B9BC5E61-0F3C-498F-AF2C-1AC16446A846'
```

It will show the row with masked value.

> maybe there is another way before inserting data to table change it value randomly

It depends on your needs. If you need to restore data you can use [column encrypting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=sql-server-2017). If you just need to uglify data you can go with a regular DB trigger or just change value from front-end as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really helped to me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into DDM_Student_Sample values (NEWID(),'Stuart Little Joe')
```